# Estimate line in [theta, rho]-space given 2 points

Tags: vectors, estimation

Given 2 points (x1,y1), (x2,y2) I wish to estimate a line defined by [cos(θ) sin(θ) -r], where r is the distance from origin to the line along a vector perpendicular to the line, and the angle theta is between the x-axis and the vector.

I am not quite sure, how one would do this.

Comment: I have no idea what this means!

Comment: I am given 2 points on a line as shown in this image: https://www.google.dk/search?q=hough+space+estimate+line+given+2+points&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=585&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi46Lr73-_MAhVLESwKHUCAAuMQ_AUIBigB&dpr=1.1#imgrc=rvbnewTUpeLpuM%3A   - and I then want to describe the line by using theta and r.

Comment: Find the equation of the line through $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ (the red line in the image). Find its gradient $k$. Then the gradient of the perpendicular (blue) line is $-\frac{1}{k}$. That gives you $\tan\theta$. To get $r$ either use the formula for the distance of the origin from a line whose equation you know, or find the point of intersection of the red and blue lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find the slope of the line, $m = \tan \theta$ (where $\theta$ is the angle made by the line to the *positive x axis*) by using

$$
m = tan \theta = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}
$$

Hence,
$$\theta = \tan^{-1}m 
$$

Next, find the equation of the line with point-slope form:

$$
y - y_1 = m(x - x_1) \\
y - y_1 - mx + mx_1 = 0 \\
- mx + y + (- y_1 + mx_1) = 0 \ \ \text{(equation of line)}
$$

Now that you have the slope, the next thing you wanted was the perpendicular distance from the origin. This is equal to
$$
d = \frac{|c|}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}
$$

where $a, b, c$ are the coefficients of the general line equation

$$
ax + by + c = 0
$$

Comparing to our line equation,

$$
a = -m \\
b = 1 \\
c = -y_1 + mx_1
$$

And hence

$$
r = \frac{|-y_1 + mx_1|}{\sqrt{(-m)^2 + 1}} = \frac{|y_1 - mx_1|}{\sqrt{(m)^2 + 1}} 
$$

Comment: I have tried implementing it like this:                                                    %theta is given as inverse tangens to the slope of the line: 
m = (x2(2)-x1(2))/(x2(1)-x1(1));
theta = atan(m);

%r is found by considering the general line equation
radius = abs(x1(2)+m*x1(1))/(sqrt(m^2+1));

       
 %The line between the 2 points in homogeneuos coordinates is then: 
 l = [cos(theta) sin(theta) -radius];                           but when I try to plot the line l it doesnt seem to go through the points at all - It actually looks like it is perpendicular to the wanted line :(

Comment: but when I use tan^(1)(-1/k) instead of m, as described in an earlier comment i get the right direction of the line, but then it doesn't go through the points.

Comment: You maybe using the "wrong" function call. Don't use $atan(m)$, use $atan2(y_2 - y_1, x_2 - x_1)$ since the latter takes care of the positive and negative signs of numerator and denominator separately :)

Comment: See (this for more info about the difference between $atan$ and $atan2$) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283406/what-is-the-difference-between-atan-and-atan2-in-c]

Comment: ooh yeah - great, thanks :)